# Enforce MFA for AWS console login but not for API calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am looking to enforce all IAM users(local and remote) to enable and activate their MFA devices.
I want them all to enable MFA to do their respective tasks.

I am trying with the following policy

```json
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {"Bool": {"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"}}
}
```

However; this policy applies irrespective of how you are accessing the services, through console or through APIs.

There is a lot of automation done by all users and their automation breaks as MFA authentication was not implied.

As a first step, we wish everybody to at least enables MFA for console login; but the same should not enforce them to use MFA for API calls used in automation.

Is this achievable through IAM policy?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a proper answer for this now @ 2022 , because even i do have the same requirement and the below anwers are not helping me

Answer (score 33):

The trick is to reverse the check...rather than only allowing if aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent is true, deny if it's false.

Here's the doc on self-service MFA management: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_users-self-manage-mfa-and-creds.html

The full policy suggested in there is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllUsersToListAccounts",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action":[
                "iam:ListAccountAliases",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToSeeAndManageTheirOwnAccountInformation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action":[
                "iam:ChangePassword",
                "iam:CreateAccessKey",
                "iam:CreateLoginProfile",
                "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
                "iam:DeleteLoginProfile",
                "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:GetLoginProfile",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
                "iam:UpdateLoginProfile",
                "iam:ListSigningCertificates",
                "iam:DeleteSigningCertificate",
                "iam:UpdateSigningCertificate",
                "iam:UploadSigningCertificate",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToListTheirOwnMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action":[
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ListMFADevices"
            ],
            "Resource":[
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:mfa/*",
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/${aws:username}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToManageTheirOwnMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action":[
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:RequestSmsMfaRegistration",
                "iam:FinalizeSmsMfaRegistration",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource":[
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:mfa/${aws:username}",
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/${aws:username}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "BlockAnyAccessOtherThanAboveUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": "iam:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition":{
                "BoolIfExists":{ "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The most important part is the last statement, which does the deny. If you change it to this:

```
{
    "Sid": "BlockAnyAccessOtherThanAboveUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "NotAction": "iam:*",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition":{
        "Bool":{ "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"}
    }
}
```

(BoolIfExists changed to Bool) it will allow IAM access keys to bypass the requirement of MFA, while still requiring you to use MFA when logging in through the AWS Console. (**Note**: this doesn't work for all APIs; some, such as ECR, always supply the "MultiFactorAuthPresent" property, which breaks this work-around)

Be careful if you decide to use that full policy from the docs. Note that it allows a user to create access keys and change their password, and the deny clause only blocks non-IAM actions...this means that, if MFA gets disabled on an account, a user's password could be changed or new access keys could be provisioned without an MFA check, and if you've made the Bool change, those new access keys would be able to access anything that the user has permissions for, without MFA. I.E., all of the security vulnerabilities of unsecured keys, with some potential for account hijacking on top.

I would suggest using a policy similar to this instead:

**Note: This policy should not be used verbatim, due to security issues mentioned in the comments**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllUsersToListAccounts",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListAccountAliases",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToSeeTheirAccountInformation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary",
                "iam:GetLoginProfile"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/${aws:username}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToListTheirMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ListMFADevices"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:mfa/*",
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/${aws:username}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToManageThierMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:mfa/${aws:username}",
                "arn:aws:iam::accountid:user/${aws:username}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DoNotAllowAnythingOtherThanAboveUnlessMFAd",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": "iam:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this is a really great solution, thanks. The only problem is that it is not compatible with docker. :( If you use AWS ECR with docker, for some reason docker calls has a `"MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"` property, so docker calls are denied. I ended up adding `"ecr:*"` to the `"NotAction"` exception list.

Comment: Do NOT use this policy.  It allows the MFA requirement to be bypassed as described in https://duo.com/blog/potential-gaps-in-suggested-amazon-web-services-security-policies-for-mfa This is due to allowing `iam:DeactivateMFADevice` without MFA.

Comment: The recommended policy has changed a bit since this answer was posted (and as @0xdabbad00 mentions, the policy in the answer in its current form may be insecure)—however, the bit about changing the `BoolIfExists` to a `Bool` is spot-on, and allows users to log into Console with TFA, but use CLI/API without.

Comment: This does not work for me.  Adding the DoNotAllowAnythingOtherThanAboveUnlessMFAd portion of the policy and making an API request gives me the error `[user] is not authorized to perform: [action] with an explicit deny`.  Removing this portion allows the API request to go through.

Comment: Need to add `ssm:*` and `kms:*` for it to work. Same as @endrec 's reasoning.

Comment: As an update, you can now add this as a "Bool" to condition: `"aws:ViaAWSService": "false"` this will account for all resources even if they always supply the property which previously broke the work around.

Answer (score 11):

Create 2 IAM users for each person:

1. one for AWS Console sign-in which enforces MFA, and
2. one for API usage that doesn't have a password and that does not enforce MFA

Comment: I would prefer having just one user. Thanks anyways

Comment: This is not a totally bad suggestion (as to deserve two downvotes.. I voted it up one point :-). I've been considering this same question, and while I have a functional MFA enforcement (following [this blog post](https://www.trek10.com/blog/improving-the-aws-force-mfa-policy-for-IAM-users/)), it will block API calls without modifications. Since the non-MFA API logins are by definition less secure than the MFA-protected console logins, it is not a bad idea to give permissions more selectively (per need) for users' API access. It is more complex, but if security is the primary consideration...

Answer (score 8):

Posting for posterity.
I tried using the methods posted by Josh Hancock but the api calls from enforced console MFA accounts fail for some AWS services like elastic filesystem and some s3 api calls. 
When raised a support ticket, the response from AWS was that, "There is a feature request for this precise issue as there is currently no reliable mechanism to enforce MFA for the console only. I have added your account to the list of requesting accounts for this feature request. Unfortunately, I do not have a reliable workaround other than enable MFA everywhere, or only apply the IAM MFA policy to users that are console only."

Comment: I have been looking into this a lot in the past couple of months, and it seems it's impossible to solidly enforce MFA for the web console while not enforcing it for any of the CLI commands (for the same user). The reason being is that the AWS web console is basically a front-end for some of the APIs available through the CLI on a lower level.

To make MFA use feasible on CLI, I have been working on a script available on [GitHub](https://github.com/605data/aws_scripts) (the `awscli-mfa` directory), and documented on my [blog](http://fetch.link/2zP4GPt).

Answer (score 6):

I have a different solution. I have a "ForceMFA" group, which doesn't allow you to do anything (other than assign MFA) unless you have MFA enabled. I have a small script that runs every hour that scans all users and adds any users without MFA to the "ForceMFA" group. The same script also removes users that have MFA enabled from the group. This way, I enforce people to enable MFA, but don't require MFA for API calls.

Here's the small Powershell 6 script I use: https://gist.github.com/kalpik/36beffd25bda2a0c38905176f7e557aa

Comment: This seems to the closest solution, at least when the script is present ;)

Comment: Added the script to my original answer :)

Answer (score 6):

After a few years of waiting. AWS finally provide a way to do this.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mfa-iam-user-aws-cli/

```
{
  "Sid": "BlockMostAccessUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "NotAction": [
    "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
    "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
    "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
    "iam:EnableMFADevice",
    "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
    "iam:ListAccountAliases",
    "iam:ListUsers",
    "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
    "iam:ListAccessKeys",
    "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
    "iam:ListMFADevices",
    "iam:GetAccountSummary",
    "sts:GetSessionToken"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "Bool": {
      "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false",
      "aws:ViaAWSService": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This definitely worked. I first added the `ssm:*` and `kms:*` according to the note Josh Hancock's answer:

`(Note: this doesn't work for all APIs; some, such as ECR, always supply the "MultiFactorAuthPresent" property, which breaks this work-around)`

Which worked but I was concerned I would have to keep track of all the resources that breaks the work around.

But now we can add this condition: ` "aws:ViaAWSService": "false"` that works for all resources!

Thanks a ton for this

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you probably found the solution to this already, but here's an official guide from the AWS Security team on setting up MFA on login for IAM users if anyone is struggling with this too:

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2SJJYE082KBUK/How-to-Delegate-Management-of-Multi-Factor-Authentication-to-AWS-IAM-Users

Basically, this can be achieved by creating a few User Groups and doing checks on whether MFA is set or not upon login.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, it's sufficient to just activate an MFA device for the IAM user. This will require the user to provide an MFA code whenever they sign into the AWS Management Console, but not for AWS API calls.

Writing an IAM policy using the "MultiFactorAuthPresent" condition is only needed if you also want to enforce MFA for API calls.

Btw, posting AWS-related questions on the AWS forums (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa) is a great way to get responses.

Comment: Yeah, that will work. However; my intention is to enforce users to activate their MFA. Many users work remote.

Comment: I disagree.  The reason I'm researching this is that I just discovered a user who had disabled their MFA.  And it's possible that a new user could be created without MFA (or one for whom we do not need to enforce MFA, eg a read-only user who just runs reports could have more roles added).