# Forced MFA policy with programmatic access

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

I'm looking into the following. I have several AWS users in my account. Some users have console access and programmatic access. All users have a policy attached that enforces the use of MFA. For users that want to access AWS programmatically, this is a problem. For normal access, I know they can just add the token in the CLI. But the problem I have is when we run an automatic process from one of those accounts. You can't just add the MFA token in your code because the token changes, but the forced MFA policy prevents access to AWS which causes an error.

The only working solution I have now is using seperate users for concole access and programmatic access and only enforcing MFA on the console access user. But this is a silly solution and requires people to manage seperate user accounts.

Does anybody have a better solution? I tried to change the force MFA policy so it would only require MFA to work with console access or so it would require a connected MFA device, not an MFA login. But that didn't work.

Sorry if anything is unclear, English is obviously not my first language, please do ask if you need more details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177505/enforce-mfa-for-aws-console-login-but-not-for-api-calls

Comment: Ah thank you! I hadn't found that one because I'm not searching for API, just programmatic, I guess. I'll look into it but first glance it seems like there is no real solution (yet?). I already tried changing up the force MFA policy to something mentioned in the answers there: 'aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent is true, deny if it's false'

Comment: I think the real solution is to not use IAM users for automated operational processes. Run those on EC2 with IAM roles, if you can. Create independent IAM users for them if you cannot use IAM roles.

Comment: Thank you! That's actually a really good suggestion I hadn't thought of at all. I'll look into it.