# AWS SES: User is not authorized to perform ses:SendEmail on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, amazon-ses

I have the following Python/boto3 script, taken directly from the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-python.html):

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
# This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
SENDER = "mailman@sender.com"

# Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
# is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
RECIPIENT = "joe@receiver.com"

# If necessary, replace us-west-2 with the AWS Region you're using for Amazon SES.
AWS_REGION = "eu-central-1"

# The subject line for the email.
SUBJECT = "Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)"

# The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
BODY_TEXT = ("Amazon SES Test (Python)\r\n"
             "This email was sent with Amazon SES using the "
             "AWS SDK for Python (Boto).")

# The HTML body of the email.
BODY_HTML = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)</h1>
  <p>This email was sent with
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses/'>Amazon SES</a> using the
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/'>
      AWS SDK for Python (Boto)</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
            """

# The character encoding for the email.
CHARSET = "UTF-8"

# Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
client = boto3.client(
    'ses', aws_access_key_id='AKIA[REDACTED]', aws_secret_access_key='[REDACTED]',
    region_name=AWS_REGION
)

# Try to send the email.
try:
    # Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_HTML,
                },
                'Text': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                },
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': SUBJECT,
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER,
    )
# Display an error if something goes wrong. 
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

Both domains (sender.com and receiver.com) are verified in SES; SES is still in sandbox mode. The AWS credentials I am using are for a user with the following policy attached (via its group):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I'm running the script I get the following error:

```
User `arn:aws:iam::[REDACTED]:user/[REDACTED]' is not authorized to perform `ses:SendEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:[REDACTED]:identity/receiver.com'.
```

When using "Send test email" from the AWS console with the same parameters everything works as expected.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Could you please post the IAM Role / Group / Policies associated with this user and also specify if the user/account you're using on the web is different from the one that owns these credentials?

Comment: @Andre.IDK the policy above is the only one attached to the user and it's coming from its group (I've edited the question to reflect this).

Comment: I see, this looks like the managed policy called ``. If this is the case the policy should be enough, but you can verify that this user actually has access to SES via Web Console by going to IAM -> Users -> {user} -> Access Advisor, in this tab you can type SES and it will tell you whether or not the user has access to it and if so, which policy/role is granting it.
Alternatively you can manually attach a policy to that user that explicitly grants them `ses:SendEmail` and `ses:SendRawEmail` on the resource.

Comment: Checked and SES is showing up in Access Advisor along with the policy above. I've added a policy explicitly allowing SendEmail but getting the same error: ```{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action":["ses:SendEmail","ses:SendRawEmail"],"Resource":"*"}]}```

Comment: Try to add another recipient , verify it and test it again. and please  let us know what version of boto3 are you using ?

Comment: Tried with a verified email address, same result; boto3==1.14.21.

Comment: Can you please try to use these same credentials in the CLI to see if you can do other operations, like list buckets (`aws s3 ls`)? If that works, try to create a s3 client with the credentials and try it programmatically and see if you getthe same list. This should at least tell us if the credentials you're using actually have admin access.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was generated by an "enforce multi-factor authentication" policy, similar to the one in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage.html); this policy enforces MFA for both the console and API (i.e., when using long-lived credentials) and denies any action missing it:

```
{
    "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "NotAction": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:GetUser",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "sts:GetSessionToken"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
       "BoolIfExists": {
           "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
       }
    }
}
```

To fix this `BoolIfExists` can be changed to `Bool`, but also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41050898/418609).

And always check **all** your IAM Policies!