# "NotAuthorizedException/" while trying to send email using AWS SES API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm try to send emails using AWS SES API in lua by making HTTPS request, but I'm getting "NotAuthorizedException/" in response object body. Can someone please help with me with understanding why this error and possible resolution to this.

For creating AWS signature version 4, I'm using [this](https://github.com/carnei-ro/kong-sns-plugin/blob/master/src/v4.lua) code.

for calling the API,

```html
local aws_v4            = require ("kong.plugins.kong-rate-limit.ses.v4")

local http              = require "resty.http"
local cjson             = require "cjson.safe"
local meta              = require "kong.meta"
local constants         = require "kong.constants"
local resty_http        = require 'resty.http'

local tostring          = tostring
local tonumber          = tonumber
local type              = type
local fmt               = string.format
local ngx_encode_base64 = ngx.encode_base64
local ngx_time          = ngx.time
local string_match      = string.match
local os_time           = os.time
local concat            = table.concat

local AWS_PORT = 443

local function iso8601_to_epoch(date_iso8601)
    local inYear, inMonth, inDay, inHour, inMinute, inSecond, inZone = string_match(date_iso8601, '^(%d%d%d%d)-(%d%d)-(%d%d)T(%d%d):(%d%d):(%d%d)(.-)$')
    local zHours, zMinutes = string_match(inZone, '^(.-):(%d%d)$')
    local returnTime = os_time({year=inYear, month=inMonth, day=inDay, hour=inHour, min=inMinute, sec=inSecond, isdst=false})
    if zHours then
      returnTime = returnTime - ((tonumber(zHours)*3600) + (tonumber(zMinutes)*60))
    end
    return returnTime
  end
  
  local function get_keys_from_metadata(iam_role,metadata_url)
    local httpc = resty_http:new()
    httpc:set_timeout(300) -- set timeout to 300ms
  
    local res, err = httpc:request_uri(metadata_url .. iam_role, {
          ssl_verify = false,
          keepalive  = false
    })
  
    if err then
      kong.log.err("Could not get keys from meta-data endpoint")
    end
  
    if not res then
      kong.log.err("Empty response from meta-data endpoint")
    end
  
    if res.status ~= 200 then
      kong.log.err("Not OK (HTTP 200) response from meta-data endpoint")
    end
  
    local body = cjson.decode(res.body)
    local expiration = iso8601_to_epoch(body.Expiration) - ngx_time() -- aws keys auto regenerates 5 min before expiration. Maybe have to change this.
    return { ["AccessKeyId"] = body.AccessKeyId, ["SecretAccessKey"] = body.SecretAccessKey, ["Token"] = body.Token }, nil, expiration
  end
  
  
  local function get_keys_from_cache(iam_role,metadata_url,override_ttl,ttl)
      if override_ttl then
        local cred, err = kong.cache:get(iam_role .. "_cred", {ttl=ttl} , get_keys_from_metadata, iam_role, metadata_url)
      else
        local cred, err = kong.cache:get(iam_role .. "_cred", nil , get_keys_from_metadata, iam_role, metadata_url)
      end
      if err then
          kong.log.err("Could not get/put ",err)  
      end
      if cred then
        return cred.AccessKeyId, cred.SecretAccessKey, cred.Token
      end
      return nil
  end

  local function publish_to_ses(client, request)
    local res, err = client:request {
      method = "GET",
      path = request.url,
      body = request.body,
      headers = request.headers
    }
    
    return res
  end  
  
  
  return {
  
      publish = function(conf, body, email_body, notified_key)
  
                    
        local message_body=ngx.escape_uri("This is body")
        local email_subject = ngx.escape_uri("This is subject")
        local source = ngx.escape_uri("example@gmail.com")
        local host = fmt("email.%s.amazonaws.com", conf.aws_region)
        local path = "/"
        
        local query = concat({'Version=2010-12-01&Action=SendEmail&Source=' , source, '&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=', source ,'&Message.Subject.Data=', email_subject,'&Message.Body.Text.Data=' , message_body})
        local port = conf.port or AWS_PORT
  
        local aws_key, aws_secret, aws_token
        if conf.aws_key == nil and conf.aws_secret == nil and conf.aws_iam_role ~= nil then
          if conf.store_creds_in_cache then
            aws_key, aws_secret, aws_token = get_keys_from_cache(conf.aws_iam_role, conf.aws_metadata_url, conf.override_cache_creds_ttl, conf.cache_creds_ttl)
          else
            local cred, e, ttl = get_keys_from_metadata(conf.aws_iam_role, conf.aws_metadata_url)
            if cred and e == nil then
              aws_key, aws_secret, aws_token = cred.AccessKeyId, cred.SecretAccessKey, cred.Token
            end
          end
        else
          aws_key = conf.aws_key
          aws_secret = conf.aws_secret
        end
  
        local opts = {
          region = conf.aws_region,
          service = "ses",
          method = "GET",
          headers = {
            ["Content-Type"] = "text/plain",
          },
          path = path,
          host = host,
          port = port,
          access_key = aws_key,
          secret_key = aws_secret,
          query = query
        }
  
        if aws_token then
          opts["headers"]['X-Amz-Security-Token'] = aws_token
        end
  
        local request, err = aws_v4(opts)
        if err then
          kong.log.err("An unexpected error occurred while signing request according to AWS signature(V4)",err)
        end
  
        -- Trigger request
        local client = http.new()
        client:set_timeout(conf.timeout)
        client:connect(host, port)
        local ok, err = client:ssl_handshake()
        if not ok then
          kong.log.err("[SES]An unexpected error occurred while connecting:  ",err)
        end
  
        local res = publish_to_ses(client, request)
        if not res then
          if conf.policy == "local" then
            service_in_memory:delete(notified_key)
          else
            res = publish_to_ses(client, request)  
          end  
                  
        end
  
        local content = res:read_body()
        
        local ok, err = client:close()
        if not ok then
          kong.log.err("[SES]Could not close connection :",err)
        end
  
        if res.status == 200 then
          local MessageId=content:match("MessageId>(.*)</MessageId")
          content=cjson.encode({
            MessageId=MessageId,
          })
        end
  
        kong.log.info("[SES]Message published: ", content)
      
      end,
  
  }
```

**I'm TRYING TO GET CREDENTIALS FROM AWS EC2 METADATA**

Any small help will help me a lot,
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you have a bug in your code somewhere, code that we can't see! 
Provide code snippets you are trying to and "AuthorizationErrors" occurs when your user doesn't have permission to access that resource.

Comment: refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63725466/aws-ses-user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-sessendemail-on-resource.

Comment: @Mayur can you please have a look into the code, "publish" function is where execution starts.  thank you