# AWS IAM. Enforce MFA in web but not CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Looking to migrate users over slowly and wondering if it's possible to enable MFA in web UI only but not CLI.

I have the following to allow users to setup MFA

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAllUsersToListAccounts",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:ListUsers",
        "iam:ListAccountAliases"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToSeeTheirAccountInformation",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:GetLoginProfile",
        "iam:GetAccountSummary",
        "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::470196620241:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToListTheirMFA",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:ListMFADevices"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::470196620241:user/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::470196620241:mfa/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowIndividualUserToManageThierMFA",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::470196620241:user/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::470196620241:mfa/${aws:username}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAllWithoutMFA",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "BoolIfExists": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That works but looking to say the user can

```
aws s3 ls
```

In cli without using MFA but it only works if MFA is setup

Comment: Related: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=908709 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177505/enforce-mfa-for-aws-console-login-but-not-for-api-calls

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, unfortunately this is not possible since both the console and CLI use the same set of permissions.