# How to write an AWS IAM policy to enforce MFA without enabling AWS cli MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to find the best way to go about writing an AWS policy such that users are required to use MFA for console access, but they aren't required to use MFA for cli access. Based of this AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage.html) it appears as though most policies are use `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent` I am trying to find a way to write a policy that checks something like `aws:MultiFactorAuthEnabled`. This way users can still use the cli, but only if they have multifactor auth enabled, not checking if multifactor auth present.

```
{
            "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "sts:GetSessionToken"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177505/enforce-mfa-for-aws-console-login-but-not-for-api-calls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [enforce MFA for AWS console login, but not for API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177505/enforce-mfa-for-aws-console-login-but-not-for-api-calls)

Answer (score 1):

The best way around this scenario is to create two groups `services` and `users` apply the MFA policy to `users`. This way we can still allow for programmatic access without MFA, but enforce MFA for human users.